# What is the language used in Azure DevOps to write expressions?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm writing my first pipeline in Azure DevOps and I would like to better understand what I'm doing.
To express a condition anywhere in a github action I would do:

```yaml
if: ${{ python.version }} == "3.9"
```

Following what I found on the web it seems I should use this in Azure:

```yaml
condition: eq(variable["python.version"]) == "3.9"
```

what is this language and where can I found it's specifications ? (It looks like Fortran conditions but it cannot be.)

Comment: I think its just YAML

Comment: @JochemQuery YAML is just a markup language and does nothing itself. Azure DevOps parses it and has its own expressions to execute. You can get the references [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Cid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8398549/cid) for the link.

Azure DevOps pipelines are using their own parsing tool to read expressions. The complete reference can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops).

As a take home information, be aware that expressions can be evaluated at run-time using the following syntax:

```yaml
a: $[ <expression> ]
```

Or at compilation time using the following syntax:

```yaml
a: ${{ <expression> }}
```

Chosing between the will depend on the context variables you need to access.